# Determine Chrome Platform Version

Tags: google-chrome-app

Is there someway to determine the Chrome platform version in order to verify that I can use APIs that are marked v37 and later? If there is an alternative way of verifying that these new parameters are supported by the current install that works as well. My current solution is to check for the existence of a different v37 API which seems to be working, however if there is a sanctioned way that would make me feel a bit better about the whole thing :).

I need to use the 'scopes' portion of this API:
[chrome.identity.getAuthToken](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity#method-getAuthToken).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In its [Cog Chrome App](https://github.com/beaufortfrancois/cog-chrome-app/blob/master/src/main.js#L59), François Beaufort is using userAgent with a regex to get the chrome version:

```js
window.alert(
navigator.userAgent.match('Chrome/([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*)')[1]
);
```

**But there is maybe a better way to check if some html/js API are available or not...**

Comment: Doh - thanks. Bit embarrassing of a question now, thanks for the quick answer :).

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a minimum version to your manifest, so you don't even have to check in your code. This will prevent the app from webstore installs who are on older versions.

```
"minimum_chrome_version": "37",
```